# Using Group By with Summarize on alphanumeric field in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, table, statistics

Is it possible to create from Summarize option, a new table with the COUNT of a string field and the code of municipalities, in my case, like that:

```
+-------------------+--------------+
| id_municipalities | string_value |
+-------------------+--------------+
| 1                 | A            |
| 1                 | A            |
| 1                 | C            |
| 2                 | A            |
| 2                 | B            |
| 3                 | D            |
+-------------------+--------------+
```

And the result table, like that:

```
+-------------------+--------------------+---------------+
| id_municipalities | COUNT_string_Value |  string_value |
+-------------------+--------------------+---------------+
| 1                 | 2                  | A             |
| 2                 | 1                  | B             |
| 3                 | 1                  | D             |
+-------------------+--------------------+---------------+
```

Answer (score 9):

This uses the [Summary Statistics](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00080000001z000000) tool rather than Summarize from the Attribute Table window but I think achieves the correct values - you may just need to re-order and delete some fields once you are satisfied the correct values are coming through.

[image]